# Express routes invoking multiple router function

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I've created a NodeJS Express app. But my express route is invocking multiple routes function, one after another, but I only need one at a time.

My express app.js

```
app.use(routes)
```

Express router:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/product", controller.productFunction)
router.post("/user", controller.userFunction)
router.get("/:id", idController.getId)
```

Whenever I create a post request for `"/product"` route, first the `productFunction` is invocked, but then the `"/:id"` routes `getId` function is also get invocked. Same thing happen for `/user` route as well. Always `/:id` route is getting invocked.
Is there any way to prevent this?

I even tried this way, but after the homepage loading then again it invockes `getId` function.

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(..........);
});

app.use(routes);
```

Comment: How are you making the POST requests?  Please show us that code/html that causes the POST.   I would guess that the problem is on the client-side of things.

Comment: What's the value of `req.params.id` in the `getId` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that this is not an issue with the router itself.

You can't skip from POST to GET handling. So invocations are caused by different requests.

`router.get("/:id", idController.getId)` kind of wild card, and `<server_url>/favicon.ico` will trigger it
If you check it via browser it tries to get favicon or smth else and invokes this handler.

Try to make `POST` request via curl/Postman and `idController.getId` should not be called.

It is risky to serve static and process requests on a same level.
You can add some prefix to all your request, like that `app.use('/api', routes);` then static file will be available on `/<file_name>` and all server logic will be under `/api/<request>`